# Failure to get html from minecraft.net

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape the minecraft.net downloads page to get the bedrock server script. When I use a python get request it hangs. It does not hang for any other website, instead returning a code 200 success.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock")

print(r)
```

Comment: A GET request? Can you perform the same one from a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try add User-Agent to the headers. Worked for me

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) ..'}
response = requests.get("https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock", headers=headers)
```